# How to get top five calculations only to appear

Tags: php, mysql

I have a dog show website and attempting to display the top five kennel affixes with the most point gained over a year.

I have split up the point as seen in code and using an inner join on two tables. One being Results and the Other Dogs

I am having a problem showing the affix name with its points gained next to it. Also can not get the top five based on most points

> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in xxx on line 59
>   Notice: Undefined variable: total in xxx on line 68

This below is all that shows up and I think it is adding the if statements up.

```
3
6
```

Sorry not that great at and need some help.

```
<?php
        $query = "SELECT result.placement, result.award, result.class_name, dogs.affix
        FROM result
        INNER JOIN dogs
        ON result.resultID = dogs.dog_id
        ORDER BY dogs.affix LIMIT 5";

        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){


            $affix          = $row['affix'];
            $placement      = $row['placement'];
            $award          = $row['award'];

            if($award === 'BCC'){
                $points = $affix + 5;
            }
            if($award === 'DCC'){
                $points = $affix + 5;
            }
            if($award === 'RBCC'){
                $points = $affix + 4;
            }
            if($award === 'RDCC'){
                $points = $affix + 4;
            }
            if($placement === '1st'){
                $points = $affix + 3;
            }
            if($placement === '2nd'){
                $points = $affix + 2;
            }
            if($placement === '3rd'){
                $points = $affix + 1;
            }

            $total += $points;



            echo "<li> {$affix} {$total}</li>";

        }

        ?>
```

Comment: need to see some more code

Comment: That is all the code on the page

Comment: Well it is obviously not, as there are only 47 lines here but that's not the point.

Comment: Sorry all the php code the rest is HTML Boiler plate

Comment: I see an addition assignment operator, but I don't see the initial declatation of `$total`.  Feels like we are not seeing the whole story.  I'd probably bake a CASE statement into the SELECT clause.

Comment: There are two problems addresed by warning and notice: First of all there is no initial value for `$total`. If you want it to start from '0' than state it clearly in code. Otherwise in next loop iteration `$total` will have value on which previous run ended.

Second problem is with `$affix` value which seems that is not numeric. Run your query by hand to take a look what is in `affix` column and whether it is proper numeric value!

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with the sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three problems.

1. `ORDER BY dogs.affix LIMIT 5` returns **bottom** 5 not top. It should be `ORDER BY dogs.affix DESC LIMIT 5` to get the top.
2. `affix` returns either `null` or an emprty string and that's why you are getting the first error. Define this field as `int not null default 0` in your database.
3. $total is not initialized. Assign it to 0 before the loop

Comment: Thank you this really helps